# Vim stop comment continuation during abbrev expansion

Tags: vim, abbreviation

If your Vim settings include 'r' in `'formatoptions'` (default) it will automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting [Enter] in insert mode, but this can be undesirable for abbrevs that expand to a single-line comment in languages that don't have separate single/multi-line comment characters.

How do I stop getting this when I press [Enter] after typing the abbrev characters?

```
# ========
#
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
" Eat one character matching the given regex from the input stream, e.g. at                                 
" the end of an abbr expansion.  (From :help abbreviations)              
func Eatchar(pat)                                    
    let c = nr2char(getchar(0))                        
    return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c                       
endfunc                                              

set pastetoggle=<F12>
iabbr <silent> sep # ========<F12><CR><F12><C-R>=Eatchar('\r')<CR>
```

This replaces the user's [Enter] key press with a generated one surrounded by generated key presses that turn paste mode off before and back on afterwards.  The final `<C-R>` completes the `<C-R>=` sequence.